# Is the $scope neccessary always for a method definition in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is clear that a method should be set to scope in order to be visible or available for the view (in html) or in a directive or in any other place where the method should be accessed, so that the method can be accessed through the $scope. My question is to know whether `$scope` is always necessary or a good practice to use when a method is defined. For instance, following are different method declarations:

**Scenario 1.** $scope.myMethod = function(){};
**Scenario 2.** var myMethod= function(){};

if 'myMethod' is only used in one controller, is it required to set it to the $scope? What are the advantages or why scenario 1 or 2 is good ?

What if someone has declared it as $scope.myMethod = function(){} ? is it not good or an unnecessary load to the $scope ? What can be the best practice?

NB: I don't need to make any poll here, please let me know any pros and cons

Answer (score 1):

You mainly use the first scenario for things like binding click events. If you will only call the `myMethod` you don't really need to define it in scope.

For example following will need the first definition:

```
<button ng-click="myMethod()">My Button</button>
```

But following can use the second:

```
angular.module('myCtrl', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  var myMethod = function (text) {alert(text)};
  $scope.mySecondMethod = function () { myMethod('second'); }
  $scope.myThirdMethod = function () { myMethod('third'); }
```

In second case you can use `mySecondMethod` and `myThirdMethod` in event binding.

Answer (score 1):

> Scope is the glue between application controller and the view. During
>   the template linking phase the directives set up $watch expressions on
>   the scope. The $watch allows the directives to be notified of property
>   changes, which allows the directive to render the updated value to the
>   DOM.
>
> Both controllers and directives have reference to the scope, but not
>   to each other. This arrangement isolates the controller from the
>   directive as well as from the DOM. This is an important point since it
>   makes the controllers view agnostic, which greatly improves the
>   testing story of the applications.

[From the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Answer (score 1):

You need `$scope` to define a method only if you are calling that function from your `html` code.

You can use `this` or `some_names` also instead of `$scope`.

`$scope` is just to mean that the function's (mehtod's) scope is inside that `controller` function and **can be accessible from the html code that written inside the controller**

If the function is calling inside the `javascript (controller)` only, then use normal definition

`function myMethod(){}`

OR

`var myMethod = function(){}`

Declaring a `method` or `variable` as `$scope` variable is only for accessing from **DOM**. If you are creating a new variable in `$scope`. It just adding that variable to the `clousure` of `$scope` as `$scope: {first, seccond, third}`
When ever you are calling a $scope function that just returns from the `closure`. There is not much load to the $scope I guess

Comment: Thanks for answer. What if someone has declared it as $scope.myMethod = function(){} ? is it not good or unnecessary load to the scope ?

Comment: @Débora Declaring a `method` or `variable` as `$scope` variable is only for accessing from **DOM**. If you are creating a new variable in `$scope`. It just adding that variable to the `clousure` of `$scope` as `$scope: {first, seccond, third}`
When ever you are calling a $scope function that just returns from the `closure`. There is not much load to the $scope I guess

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1**. $scope.myMethod = function(){};

**Scenario 2**. var myMethod= function(){};

> Scope is the glue between the controller and the view. If you really
>   need any variable and methods for the current view, then this should
>   be added to the scope variable. Please see the controller as property
>   if you don't want to add the methods to scope.

**Scenario 1**
If you declare a method using the scope, then this will be available/accessed from the view.

**Scenario 2**
If you really don't need this method to be accessed from the view, then you can remove this method from the scope.